# Attach event to a class

Tags: c#, events, event-handling, windows-phone

I'm trying to register an event to the **MainPage.xaml.cs** like this :

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{

public static ICanvas CurrentCanvas;


private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    //HERE I TRY TO REGISTER FOR MY EVENT

    ((WP8Canvas)CurrentCanvas).Redraw += WP8EventHandler_RedrawCanvas;

    //HERE I TRY TO REGISTER FOR MY EVENT/

    System.Threading.ThreadStart start = new System.Threading.ThreadStart(launchProcessA);
    System.Threading.Thread t = new System.Threading.Thread(start);
    t.Name = "ProcessA Thread";
    t.Start();

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Listen to WP8Canvas repaint() methods
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    public void WP8EventHandler_RedrawCanvas(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        wpCanvas.InvalidateArrange();
        Debug.WriteLine("Redraw Canvas Event"); 
    }

}
```

**WP8Canvas.cs**

```
public class WP8Canvas : WP8Displayable, ICanvas
{
    public Canvas canvas ;
    public event EventHandler Redraw;
    protected object reference;


    public WP8Canvas(object reference)
    {
        this.reference = reference;
        MainPage.CurrentCanvas = this;
        Debug.WriteLine("WP8Canvas instance");
    }

    public void repaint()
    {            
        RedrawCanvas();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Raise event if repaint() method is hit
    /// </summary
    private void RedrawCanvas()
    {
        //Null check makes sure the main page is attached to the event
        if (this.Redraw != null)
            this.Redraw(new object(), new EventArgs());
    }

}
```

Between my comment  *//HERE I TRY TO REGISTER FOR MY EVENT* I try to register an non-instantiated object **WP8Canvas** but of course a null exception occurs. It's my **Thread t** who controls the creation of **WP8Canvas** object but this happens during run-time and I don't know when.

**QUESTION :** How can I register my  **WP8Canvas** Redraw event to the **MainPage** without facing that null pointer exception.

Comment: Why don't you subscribe to your event in the `launchProcessA` method, right after the WP8Canvas has been instantiated?

Comment: `launchProcessA` is like "imported" code. I'm not sure this code will ask for the creation of a `WP8Canvas`. So I can't automatically subscribe to the event from this process. My idea is more like this : when `WP8Canvas` is created he just tell to the `MainPage` : "Hey listen to my **redraw** event now !". But I don't know if this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have no control over the `launchProcessA`, then a way to reach this result is to use a property:

```
public WP8Canvas CurrentWP8Canvas
{
    get
    {
        return this.CurrentCanvas as WP8Canvas;
    }

    set
    {
        this.CurrentCanvas = value;
        value.Redraw += WP8EventHandler_RedrawCanvas;
    }    
}
```

Then you juste have to change your code so that the thread assigns the `CurrentWP8Canvas` property instead of `CurrentCanvas`

**Edit:** If you need it to be static, one way could be to store the event handler in a temporary static variable:

```
public static EventHandler RedrawCanvas { get; set; }
```

Then set it from MainPage's constructor:

```
RedrawCanvas = WP8EventHandler_RedrawCanvas;
```

Finally, declare CurrentWP8Canvas as static, and assign the event handler you stored:

```
public static WP8Canvas CurrentWP8Canvas
{
    get
    {
        return CurrentCanvas as WP8Canvas;
    }

    set
    {
        CurrentCanvas = value;
        value.Redraw += RedrawCanvas;
    }    
}
```

It should work. However, it's terribly wrong, for many reasons: thread synchronization issues, risks of memory leaks... At that point, you're supposed to conclude that you've reached a dead-end, backtrack, and consider redesigning your architecture.

Comment: I'm trying to use your answer but I assign my `CurrentCanvas` in the constructor of `WP8Canvas` using `this`. I don't know how to do the assignation in your example. Anyway, I really appreciate your help, than you.

Comment: @Yann Instead of `MainPage.CurrentCanvas = this;`, use `MainPage.CurrentWP8Canvas = this;`

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do this because `CurrentWP8Canvas` can't be static because it's a property and if I call it through a `MainPage` instance like this : `MainPage instanceMainPage = new MainPage();` `instanceMainPage.CurrentWP8Canvas = this;` , I obtain a **System.UnauthorizedAccessException**.

Comment: Thank you, this is really helpful ! I will take care of your warning.